# Why are the messages that follow after "writing" the file inside golang web handlers not displayed?

Tags: go

I'm working with golang web server and handlers and ran into a little problem. I want to serve one file with the following text. The problem is that the messages are not displayed. Here is the handler code:

```
mux := http.NewServeMux()

mux.HandleFunc("/myfile", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    http.ServeFile(w, r, "./ui/static/js/main.js")
    w.Write([]byte("Message after (1)"))
    w.Write([]byte("Message after (2)"))
    fmt.Println("Console message!")
})

http.ListenAndServe(":4000", mux)
```

The output in the browser is:

```
var navLinks = document.querySelectorAll("nav a");
for (var i = 0; i < navLinks.length; i++) {
    var link = navLinks[i]
    if (link.getAttribute('href') == window.location.pathname) {
        link.classList.add("live");
        break;
    }
}
```

But when I write one message (or more) before the file, it shows both the messages after and before the file:

```
mux := http.NewServeMux()

mux.HandleFunc("/myfile", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Write([]byte("Message 1 (before)"))
    http.ServeFile(w, r, "./ui/static/js/main.js")
    w.Write([]byte("Message 1 (after)"))
    w.Write([]byte("Message 2 (after)"))
    fmt.Println("Console message!")
})

http.ListenAndServe(":4000", mux)
```

The output in the browser is:

```
Message 1 (before)var navLinks = document.querySelectorAll("nav a");
for (var i = 0; i < navLinks.length; i++) {
    var link = navLinks[i]
    if (link.getAttribute('href') == window.location.pathname) {
        link.classList.add("live");
        break;
    }
}Message 1 (after)Message 2 (after)
```

Does anyone know why this happens and how to fix it? In other words, why are messages after the file not displayed when there is no message before the file?

`fmt.Println("Console message!")` is always displayed in the console.

Answer (score 2):

The net/http server does one of thee things with regards to framing the response body:

- If the application sets the response content length header before the first call to write, then the server uses identity encoding with the application specified content length header.
- If the response body fits in fixed size buffer (currently 2048 bytes), the server sets the content length header to the actual content length and uses identity encoding.
- Otherwise, the server uses chunked encoding with no content length response header.

The above refers to what the server writes to the network. The server does not update the response writer [header](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#ResponseWriter.Header) with these values.

**First example:**

The call to [http.ServeFile](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#ServeFile) sets the response content length [header](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#ResponseWriter.Header) to the size of the file before the first call to [Write](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#ResponseWriter.Write). The client reads the number of bytes specified by the content length header.

The content length does not include the size of two messages. These messages are ignored by the client or the two messages cause an error the next HTTP transaction on the network connection.

**Second example** (call to Write before ServeFile):

Modifications to the [response header](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#ResponseWriter.Header) are ignored after the first call to [Write](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#ResponseWriter.Write). The [ServeFile](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#ServeFile) function sets the response content length header to the size of the file, but that value is ignored.

The client reads the all of the messages and file because the server either used chunked encoding or set the content length header to the actual size of the file.

Some ServeFile features may work correctly because ServeFile cannot set the response headers or response status code.

**Fix**:

Open the file in your handler and copy to the response. You cannot use http.ServeFile.

Comment: If `http.ServeFile` sets the Content-Length header to the size of the file and that is all that will be displayed, then why are messages marked as "after" displayed when there are also messages marked as "before"?

Comment: If I have 2 "Writes", then the first one sets the Content-Length, but the second one can override it by increasing the existing value with the size of "it's write"?

Comment: @joke I updated the answer again. If the application sets the content length header (and I am including ServeFile in this), then that header is written to the client and that's what the client reads.  Otherwise, the server uses chunked encoding or sets the content length based on the server's own information about the size of the response.

Comment: Okay, I just have one more question. You said (even the comment about the Write function mentions it) that with "Write" call, if "WriteHeader" is not called before it and header Content-Types and Content-Length are not already set, the "Write" function will do it for us. But after `v.Write([]bite("Message 1 (before)"))` I did `fmt.Println("Header:", v.Header())` and it only prints an empty map... Shouldn't it have the Content-Length and Content-Type properties set to the appropriate values?

Comment: @joke  The net/http uses internal struct fields to record the computed content length and content type. The net/http server does not set values in the [header map](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#ResponseWriter.Header).  In addition, the content length is not determined until after the application's handler returns.

Comment: `If WriteHeader has not yet been called, Write calls WriteHeader(http.StatusOK) before writing the data. If the Header does not contain a Content-Type line, Write adds a Content-Type...`  - this is the comment related to "Write" method. What do you mean with `In addition, the content length is not determined until after the application's handler returns.`. From their "documentation" it looks like Content-Type is determined just inside "Write" function? Same story with Content-Length.

Comment: I will post this as a separate question. I think it deserves it.

Answer (score 0):

`http.ServeFile` tries to set the `Content-Length` header (along with a bunch of other headers that are good for serving static files, like `Last-Modified`). Since it sets `Content-Length` to the length of the file, the browser quits listening to you after the last byte of the file. If you do `w.Write([]byte("Message 1 (before)"))` this jumps ahead to the response body part and makes it impossible for `http.ServeFile` to set any headers.

Comment: If I have `w.Write([]byte("Message 1 (before)"))` it makes imposible for `http.ServerFile` to set any header? But then how is the content of the file displayed, if "Write" will set the Content-Length to a much smaller number?

Comment: If you don't set `Content-Length` or if you set `Connection: close` the browser will determine when the file ends based on when you terminate the TCP connection.

Comment: Okay, I get it but then I have one more question. When I just use `http.ServeFile(w, r, "./ui/static/js/main.js")` and  then `fmt.Println("Header:", w.Header())` it prints the content of header as I expect (as it should - it set content-type, content-length etc), but when I use `w.Write([]byte("Message"))` and then `fmt.Println("Header:", w.Header())` it gives an empty map. Why is this happening?

Comment: I will post this as a separate question. I think it deserves it.